# Why does fgetc only read up to a certain byte of PNG in C?

Tags: c, stdio, fgetc

I am trying to read the bytes of an image file in C, specifically a PNG, in the following manner:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  FILE* fd = fopen("logo.png", "r");
  char c = fgetc(fd);
  while(c != EOF){
    printf("%c", c);
    c = fgetc(fd);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When I run the program, I get he following:

```
<89>PNG^M
^Z
^@^@^@^MIHDR^@^@^@
```

Why does it only go to a certain byte and then completely exit reading the file?How would I fix this issue?

Comment: Also `fopen("logo.png", "r");` --> `fopen("logo.png", "rb");`  Open in binary mode.

Comment: Would it be better to use rb compared to r? Just want to have an understanding of the difference between the uses.

Comment: Some systems perform translations with files in _text_ mode.  (no `"b"`)  like `\r\n` <==> `\r`.  .png files are binary ones (add `"b"`) .   No translations needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code contains an error.

```
// Wrong
char c = fgetc(fd);
```

The correct version is:

```
// Correct
int c = fgetc(fd);
```

What is happening is the byte `0xff` appears in your PNG file somewhere.  So you get:

```
char c = 0xff;
```

But that's an overflow, and in this case it happens to result in:

```
char c = -1;
```

And `EOF` is also -1.

(Note that if you read the C standard it turns out that we've actually encountered *undefined behavior,* but a discussion of undefined behavior can turn into a rabbit hole.)

Comment: I like the last comment :D

Comment: Thank you! This fixed a bug that was in my program. The character that my code was getting stuck on was the \377. I knew the character was having the issue, but what was happening was confusing me.